# Concept for a USB RAID system by means of switch

Tags: hard-drive, usb, raid

I'm planning a domestic USB RAID system. My ideal design would be something like this:

```
 USB 3.0   _____________________________________
-----------1 [] []    [] []    [] []     [] []  |___ AV in case too many USB are connected
           1___x________x________x_________x____|
               |        |        |         |  
                    Individual switches
```

Every area has two slots, where I would leave two identical USB from the same brand.

My requirements would be

- Independent power per area, if I only turn on area 3, only area 3 is visible.
- Enough optimal autopower for not needing AV cord, at minimum when only a single area is used.
- Ideally every 2-slot area is RAID1ed by HW, if that does not exist, SW. Also a hot-backup, rebuild stage (for example left slot would be the primary reference) would be perfect
- If more than one area is turned on, bus does not suffer from performance

Is this a good idea? Does this thing exist? Can be emulated by a workaround if not?
Can somebody point to some hardware suggestions, as there are a lot of different USB switches which I always read bad reviews on design, performing and functioning

Comment: "Is this a good idea?" No. RAID is usually done for reliability and/or speed. For speed do not use USB. For reliability you do not want a lot of USB switches either.

Answer (score 1):

USB attachable devices similar the ones you are talking about exist; though you don't attach USB devices to the main device through any kind of switch, but put the drives in the device directly.

If you have existing USB external drives you are wanting to reuse in such a configuration, you can always remove the drive from the enclosure.  Of course this would not work for flash drives, but they'd be a poor choice for a RAID due to speed concerns.

The first thing that comes to mind for me is Drobo, but there are other companies.

Probably what you are wanting to search for is something like "USB RAID enclosure" or similar.

If you are really wanting to do something weird like mix and match USB flash drives and USB spinning drives in an enclosure, you may want to use a PC running something like FreeNAS for this purpose.